# Windows 10 SSD partition suddenly became Unallocated Disk Space

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, dell-optiplex

Is anybody familiar with this issue? Weather its the Windows 10, SSD or BIOS issue?

I have this Dell Optiplex 9020, then I bough a new [SSD Kingston A400](https://www.kingston.com/us/ssd/a400-solid-state-drive?partnum=SA400S37%2F240G) 
, I clean install using the latest version of Windows 10 (installer came from the official website of Microsoft).

After installation, I set it up, installed MS Office, installed the dell support assistant and updated the whole system including the windows apps.

I also updated the system bios using the dell support assistant.

Everything's working well, I shut it down, restart, shut it down, and turn it on. I regularly used the computer at least 6 hours.

3 days later, I turn on the computer and it says "No bootable device found".

I checked the bios, and noticed from the boot sequence that the Windows Boot Manager is no longer exist (I'm using UEFI). I thought I can fix it by using the windows installer and use the repair option, but no, it did not fix the issue.

Since I don't have any files on it yet, I decided to perform a clean install of it again. During installation, where you can select the drives, the SSD says "Unallocated Disk Space".

I'm so confused, I don't know what happened, I'm expecting multiple allocated space created from the previous installation of Windows. I'm thinking that maybe the culprit is the dell support assistant, it updated 5 of system firmware including the BIOS. But I could be wrong, maybe its on SSD, I own multiple types of dell machine and I'm using dell support assistant to update everything on the machine and I didn't have any issue.

Comment: I know it's a bit too late but it just happened to me as well. Did you find a fix or just reinstalled the OS?

Comment: @daydr3am3r - I did not found any solution. Something's not right and I don't know what it is. Anyway, I just reinstalled the OS, so far no issue. Maybe it's something related to the firmware update of Dell.